# Guide me to run a perl cgi program in browser,i am using windows7 and installed strawberry perl

Tags: perl, window, webserver, cgi

Please help me for this request, I am a beginner at CGI and Perl

I tried to install Perl, but I am getting the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. I believe sister site Super User can help you with web server configuration issues.

Comment: You might want to specify which server you're having problems with...

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry Perl does not include Apache, but otherwise is wonderful. You can install Apache afterwards to run CGI like you want through a webserver on your local computer. But you have to set them up and make them work together.

It sounds like you already have some version of Apache running but are having trouble in the process of setting them up and getting perl and the server to work together.

If you are wanting begin learning Perl and CGI on a Windows platform, then a perfect way to do so is with IndigoPerl. It includes a great pre-configured (rather out of date) but ready to run Apache webserver for Windows.

http://www.indigostar.com/indigoperl.php

You simply install it, and the Apache server is up and running on your localhost including perl programs.